# How to flag/moderate a comment conversation that's gone off the rails?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63926529/2602718) where I left a clarifying comment. As I watched, the comments slowly spiraled off-topic.

<sub>(OP's name is crossed out in red. Click for larger image)</sub>

[image: comment-thread]

Some of these seem pretty clearly no longer needed (OP's last comment, for instance), but what about the rest of these? There are a lot of repeated questions for OP, some partial answers and even a suggestion for OP to quit their job because their coworkers "clearly [don't] know what they are doing."

If I'm looking to help get this question and its comment thread back on track, what can I do? Mass flag all of those comments? Leave a comment of my own politely reminding users to stay on-topic? (seems rather ill-advised and condescending to me).

Comment: Well, looks like flagging the post is actually _not_ the preferred way for mods, they prefer individual flags on comments: [What is the correct procedure for handling large amounts of trashy comments on a post?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322702)